# What is the proper way of growing a json array using jq inside a bash script?

Tags: bash, jq

I am trying to construct a json array using jq element by element. The elements are being generated by a certain process. In this example I am keeping all the elements as the same, let's say `{"key_1":1}` for simplicity.

```
declare JSON_ARRAY=[]
total_count=10000
OBJECT="{\"key_1\":1}"
for i in $(seq 0 $total_count); do
  JSON_ARRAY=$(echo "$JSON_ARRAY" | jq .[$i]+="$OBJECT")
done
echo "$JSON_ARRAY" | jq -c
```

I want the output from the code above to be a json array, such as for 3 elements:

```
[{"key_1":1}, {"key_1":1}, {"key_1":1}]
```

For smaller values of `counter` this would work but for large values like 10000 this leads to `parse error` or `Aborted (core dumped)`. It seems that the script runs out of memory trying to build large arrays. What could be the reasonable approach to doing this using `jq`? In this case all the elements are identical, but in my situation the elements (each a json object) are being generated in runtime within the loop such as the following:

```
for i in $(seq 0 $total_count); do
  OBJECT=$(build_object)
  JSON_ARRAY=$(echo "$JSON_ARRAY" | jq .[$i]+="$OBJECT")
done
```

Comment: What is your expected output? Please [edit] your question to include expected output for an array with e.g. 5 elements. Is it `[{"key_1":1}, {"key_1":1}, {"other_key":42}]` or something else?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a loop (or any sequence of commands) which generates a stream of JSON objects, you can *slurp* them with jq and get your array for free.

Loop:

```
for i in $(seq 100); do
  echo '{"key": "value"}';
done | jq -s '.' > output.json
```

Sequence:

```
{
  echo '{"key": "value"}';
  echo '{"other_key": "second value"}';
  echo '{"last": 42}';
} | jq -s '.' > output.json
```